# Pyusb can't find a device while libusb can

Tags: python, python-3.x, libusb, pyusb

I have an ACR38 smartcard reader connected to my computer and I can see its *Vendor ID* and *Product ID* using *libusb-Win32 inf wizard* :
[image]

But I can't communicate with it in Python 3.4.1 via **pyusb-1.0.0a2** :

```
>>> dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x072F, idProduct=0x90CC)
>>> print(dev)
None
>>>
```

Why?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create the driver (inf file) and install it from the wizard? 
Does your device show up in the device manager as libusb device?

Comment: Oops! How I can install that inf file?!